# How to debug XHR occurring an Angular 10 application

Tags: xmlhttprequest, angular-httpclient

By default Angular 10 uses an XHR backend, but there is a JSONP backend available.
I am receiving some odd results from the `HttpClient`, which differ from the data received when using other tools to interact with the backend API.

I want to be able to see what is happening in the raw `XMLHttpRequest` traffic.  I suspect a `HttpInterceptor` is doing something funky, and when I add my own `HttpInterceptor` the payload has already been altered from what I expect to see.  Watching the XHR will "prove" this theory.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I have taken to adding some logging is to copy the XHR backend from https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/http/src/xhr.ts into a subclass.  Small changes needed to be made because not everything is exported from '@angular/common/http'.

(Note the following is MIT licensed

```
import { HttpXhrBackend, HttpHeaders, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpBackend, HttpEvent } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Observer } from 'rxjs';

import {HttpDownloadProgressEvent, HttpErrorResponse, HttpEventType, HttpHeaderResponse, HttpUploadProgressEvent} from '@angular/common/http';

const XSSI_PREFIX = /^\)\]\}',?\n/;

/**
 * Determine an appropriate URL for the response, by checking either
 * XMLHttpRequest.responseURL or the X-Request-URL header.
 */
function getResponseUrl(xhr: any): string|null {
  if ('responseURL' in xhr && xhr.responseURL) {
    return xhr.responseURL;
  }
  if (/^X-Request-URL:/m.test(xhr.getAllResponseHeaders())) {
    return xhr.getResponseHeader('X-Request-URL');
  }
  return null;
}

@Injectable()
export class CustomHttpBackend extends HttpXhrBackend {

  handle(req: HttpRequest<any>): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    console.log(req);

    // Quick check to give a better error message when a user attempts to use
    // HttpClient.jsonp() without installing the HttpClientJsonpModule
    if (req.method === 'JSONP') {
    throw new Error(
        `Attempted to construct Jsonp request without HttpClientJsonpModule installed.`);
    }

    // Everything happens on Observable subscription.
    return new Observable((observer: Observer<HttpEvent<any>>) => {
    // Start by setting up the XHR object with request method, URL, and withCredentials flag.
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(req.method, req.urlWithParams);
    if (!!req.withCredentials) {
        xhr.withCredentials = true;
    }

    // Add all the requested headers.
    Array.from(req.headers.keys())
        .forEach(key => xhr.setRequestHeader(key, req.headers.get(key)!));

    // Add an Accept header if one isn't present already.
    if (!req.headers.has('Accept')) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json, text/plain, */*');
    }

    // Auto-detect the Content-Type header if one isn't present already.
    if (!req.headers.has('Content-Type')) {
        const detectedType = req.detectContentTypeHeader();
        // Sometimes Content-Type detection fails.
        if (detectedType !== null) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', detectedType);
        }
    }

    // Set the responseType if one was requested.
    if (req.responseType) {
        const responseType = req.responseType.toLowerCase();

        // JSON responses need to be processed as text. This is because if the server
        // returns an XSSI-prefixed JSON response, the browser will fail to parse it,
        // xhr.response will be null, and xhr.responseText cannot be accessed to
        // retrieve the prefixed JSON data in order to strip the prefix. Thus, all JSON
        // is parsed by first requesting text and then applying JSON.parse.
        xhr.responseType = ((responseType !== 'json') ? responseType : 'text') as any;
    }

    // Serialize the request body if one is present. If not, this will be set to null.
    const reqBody = req.serializeBody();

    // If progress events are enabled, response headers will be delivered
    // in two events - the HttpHeaderResponse event and the full HttpResponse
    // event. However, since response headers don't change in between these
    // two events, it doesn't make sense to parse them twice. So headerResponse
    // caches the data extracted from the response whenever it's first parsed,
    // to ensure parsing isn't duplicated.
    let headerResponse: HttpHeaderResponse|null = null;

    // partialFromXhr extracts the HttpHeaderResponse from the current XMLHttpRequest
    // state, and memoizes it into headerResponse.
    const partialFromXhr = (): HttpHeaderResponse => {
        if (headerResponse !== null) {
        return headerResponse;
        }

        // Read status and normalize an IE9 bug (https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/1450).
        const status: number = xhr.status === 1223 ? 204 : xhr.status;
        const statusText = xhr.statusText || 'OK';

        // Parse headers from XMLHttpRequest - this step is lazy.
        const headers = new HttpHeaders(xhr.getAllResponseHeaders());

        // Read the response URL from the XMLHttpResponse instance and fall back on the
        // request URL.
        const url = getResponseUrl(xhr) || req.url;

        // Construct the HttpHeaderResponse and memoize it.
        headerResponse = new HttpHeaderResponse({headers, status, statusText, url});
        return headerResponse;
    };

    // Next, a few closures are defined for the various events which XMLHttpRequest can
    // emit. This allows them to be unregistered as event listeners later.

    // First up is the load event, which represents a response being fully available.
    const onLoad = () => {
        // Read response state from the memoized partial data.
        let {headers, status, statusText, url} = partialFromXhr();

        // The body will be read out if present.
        let body: any|null = null;

        if (status !== 204) {
          // Use XMLHttpRequest.response if set, responseText otherwise.
          body = (typeof xhr.response === 'undefined') ? xhr.responseText : xhr.response;
        }
        console.log(body);

        // Normalize another potential bug (this one comes from CORS).
        if (status === 0) {
          status = !!body ? 200 : 0;
        }

        // ok determines whether the response will be transmitted on the event or
        // error channel. Unsuccessful status codes (not 2xx) will always be errors,
        // but a successful status code can still result in an error if the user
        // asked for JSON data and the body cannot be parsed as such.
        let ok = status >= 200 && status < 300;

        // Check whether the body needs to be parsed as JSON (in many cases the browser
        // will have done that already).
        if (req.responseType === 'json' && typeof body === 'string') {
        // Save the original body, before attempting XSSI prefix stripping.
        const originalBody = body;
        body = body.replace(XSSI_PREFIX, '');
        try {
            // Attempt the parse. If it fails, a parse error should be delivered to the user.
            body = body !== '' ? JSON.parse(body) : null;
        } catch (error) {
            // Since the JSON.parse failed, it's reasonable to assume this might not have been a
            // JSON response. Restore the original body (including any XSSI prefix) to deliver
            // a better error response.
            body = originalBody;

            // If this was an error request to begin with, leave it as a string, it probably
            // just isn't JSON. Otherwise, deliver the parsing error to the user.
            if (ok) {
            // Even though the response status was 2xx, this is still an error.
            ok = false;
            // The parse error contains the text of the body that failed to parse.
            body = {error, text: body};// as HttpJsonParseError
            }
        }
        }

        if (ok) {
        // A successful response is delivered on the event stream.
        observer.next(new HttpResponse({
            body,
            headers,
            status,
            statusText,
            url: url || undefined,
        }));
        // The full body has been received and delivered, no further events
        // are possible. This request is complete.
        observer.complete();
        } else {
        // An unsuccessful request is delivered on the error channel.
        observer.error(new HttpErrorResponse({
            // The error in this case is the response body (error from the server).
            error: body,
            headers,
            status,
            statusText,
            url: url || undefined,
        }));
        }
    };

    // The onError callback is called when something goes wrong at the network level.
    // Connection timeout, DNS error, offline, etc. These are actual errors, and are
    // transmitted on the error channel.
    const onError = (error: ProgressEvent) => {
        const {url} = partialFromXhr();
        const res = new HttpErrorResponse({
        error,
        status: xhr.status || 0,
        statusText: xhr.statusText || 'Unknown Error',
        url: url || undefined,
        });
        observer.error(res);
    };

    // The sentHeaders flag tracks whether the HttpResponseHeaders event
    // has been sent on the stream. This is necessary to track if progress
    // is enabled since the event will be sent on only the first download
    // progress event.
    let sentHeaders = false;

    // The download progress event handler, which is only registered if
    // progress events are enabled.
    const onDownProgress = (event: ProgressEvent) => {
        // Send the HttpResponseHeaders event if it hasn't been sent already.
        if (!sentHeaders) {
        observer.next(partialFromXhr());
        sentHeaders = true;
        }

        // Start building the download progress event to deliver on the response
        // event stream.
        let progressEvent: HttpDownloadProgressEvent = {
        type: HttpEventType.DownloadProgress,
        loaded: event.loaded,
        };

        // Set the total number of bytes in the event if it's available.
        if (event.lengthComputable) {
        progressEvent.total = event.total;
        }

        // If the request was for text content and a partial response is
        // available on XMLHttpRequest, include it in the progress event
        // to allow for streaming reads.
        if (req.responseType === 'text' && !!xhr.responseText) {
        progressEvent.partialText = xhr.responseText;
        }

        // Finally, fire the event.
        observer.next(progressEvent);
    };

    // The upload progress event handler, which is only registered if
    // progress events are enabled.
    const onUpProgress = (event: ProgressEvent) => {
        // Upload progress events are simpler. Begin building the progress
        // event.
        let progress: HttpUploadProgressEvent = {
        type: HttpEventType.UploadProgress,
        loaded: event.loaded,
        };

        // If the total number of bytes being uploaded is available, include
        // it.
        if (event.lengthComputable) {
        progress.total = event.total;
        }

        // Send the event.
        observer.next(progress);
    };

    // By default, register for load and error events.
    xhr.addEventListener('load', onLoad);
    xhr.addEventListener('error', onError);
    xhr.addEventListener('timeout', onError);
    xhr.addEventListener('abort', onError);

    // Progress events are only enabled if requested.
    if (req.reportProgress) {
        // Download progress is always enabled if requested.
        xhr.addEventListener('progress', onDownProgress);

        // Upload progress depends on whether there is a body to upload.
        if (reqBody !== null && xhr.upload) {
        xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', onUpProgress);
        }
    }

    // Fire the request, and notify the event stream that it was fired.
    xhr.send(reqBody!);
    observer.next({type: HttpEventType.Sent});

    // This is the return from the Observable function, which is the
    // request cancellation handler.
    return () => {
        // On a cancellation, remove all registered event listeners.
        xhr.removeEventListener('error', onError);
        xhr.removeEventListener('abort', onError);
        xhr.removeEventListener('load', onLoad);
        xhr.removeEventListener('timeout', onError);
        if (req.reportProgress) {
        xhr.removeEventListener('progress', onDownProgress);
        if (reqBody !== null && xhr.upload) {
            xhr.upload.removeEventListener('progress', onUpProgress);
        }
        }

        // Finally, abort the in-flight request.
        if (xhr.readyState !== xhr.DONE) {
        xhr.abort();
        }
    };
    });
  }
}
```

Then in app.module.ts, add the custom provider.

```
import { HttpBackend } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CustomHttpBackend } from './path/to/custom-http-backend';

providers: [
    ...,
    {
      provide: HttpBackend,
      useClass: CustomHttpBackend,
    },
  ],
```